# Why my strings "app_name" show the package name in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I'm using the xml string and which comes by default "app_name" in the android, but when I use it shows me wrong, it shows me the package name.

This is my definition in the code:

```
<string name="app_name">App's Name</string>
```

And in the Manifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

But in the Android show me the app name how "br.com.enterprise.app"

(I can't post image because this is my first post)

A another thing that happens is when I install the app in another smartphone it show a error message and close, I think that the cause is from the same reason.

Comment: What does this `android:label="something"` in your activity refer to?

Comment: I have not seen this mistake! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer the app name in application tag like this,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I was blind, I lost 2 days with this!

Comment: Ok Welcome!! You can also add the android:label in your launcher activity also...Please accept my answer and upvote it!!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the app's name problem, add the Label property to link the String app_name to the application's name.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```